# Limit items returned in push with group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to group by senders (fleche) and get the last message from each one.. I successfuly achieve the idea with **$push** and **$group** but it return all messages for each 'fleche' (senders) . Same pb with date of messages, the last element should be enought . Is it possible on mongo 2.6.6 **with aggregation framework** ? 
result expected , actual result from my actual query , actual query, and messages collection sample attached  bellow: 
**result expected :**

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "date" : [ 
            1421948851800
        ],
        "mess" : [ 
            "dernier mess ffsdfsdfsd 2" 
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "date" : [ 
            1421948859593
        ],
        "mess" : [ 
            "dernier mess ffsdfsdfsd 2"

        ]
    }
```

**Actual result from actual query :**

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "date" : [ 
            1421948851800, 
            1421947200606, 
            1421947163929, 
            1421947153646, 
            1421946853567
        ],
        "mess" : [ 
            "dernier mess ffsdfsdfsd 2", 
            "fssdfencore didon ! fds 2", 
            "fsd fds fds 2", 
            "safdsfdsfs sdf fie2", 
            "salut la companie"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "date" : [ 
            1421948859593, 
            1421947176679, 
            1421947098168
        ],
        "mess" : [ 
            "dernier mess ffsdfsdfsd 2", 
            "fssdfsdffsd ss fds 2", 
            "salut la companie"
        ]
    }
```

**Actual query :**

```
db.messages.aggregate([

    {$match :{cible :2 , lu:0} } ,
    { $sort : { date : -1 } },
    { $group : {_id : "$fleche", date : { $push : "$date" } , mess :{$push: "$mess" }   } } ,
    {$limit:20}

])
```

**Messages collection sample :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c12fe5a48da55ee08c7804"),
    "fleche" : 1,
    "cible" : 2,
    "date" : 1421946853567,
    "mess" : "salut la companie",
    "lu" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c130daa48da55ee08c7805"),
    "fleche" : 3,
    "cible" : 2,
    "date" : 1421947098168,
    "mess" : "salut la companie",
    "lu" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c13111a48da55ee08c7807"),
    "fleche" : 1,
    "cible" : 2,
    "date" : 1421947153646,
    "mess" : "safdsfdsfs sdf fie2",
    "lu" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c1311ba48da55ee08c7808"),
    "fleche" : 1,
    "cible" : 2,
    "date" : 1421947163929,
    "mess" : "fsd fds fds 2",
    "lu" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c13128a48da55ee08c7809"),
    "fleche" : 3,
    "cible" : 2,
    "date" : 1421947176679,
    "mess" : "fssdfsdffsd ss fds 2",
    "lu" : 0
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't really read the question, but use $first instead of $pull and see what happens

Comment: use $last @user4406273

Comment: what a beautifull trick , exellent !

Comment: @Disposer - You could post a working solution so that it would be helpful for others.

Comment: thanks @BatScream ;). I just wanted to help, really doesn't deserve to be an answer

Comment: @Disposer - that's fine. Will vote to close as not able to replicate anymore :)

Comment: @BatScream, I posted the answer, thanks for support ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [**$last**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)

```
db.messages.aggregate([

    {$match :{cible :2 , lu:0} } ,
    { $sort : { date : -1 } },
    { $group : {_id : "$fleche", date : { $first : "$date" } , mess :{$first: "$mess" }   } } ,
    {$limit:20}

])
```

the output will be:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "date" : 1421947163929,
            "mess" : "fsd fds fds 2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "date" : 1421947176679,
            "mess" : "fssdfsdffsd ss fds 2"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @Disposer do you think its possible to have a count result ignoring the $limit ? it could be nice for pagination , am i force  to count the total in a separate query ?

Comment: @user4406273 pagination would be difficult in aggregation, I'm not home for a few days, but Im gonna work on it

Comment: @4406273, as aggregation returns its reasult as a document not a cursor, there is no other way than $limit, but you can use **allowDiskUse (link)** http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ and store result in another collection, then query your new collection, no other way comes to my mind ;)